# What is a conventional name for a set of values having no properties except that values are distinct?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology, type-theory

I know essentially nothing about math but I'm interested in very low-level concepts.

I'm thinking of something like a finite or infinite set (although I'm not married to consider sets per se, maybe some relevant stuff is from category theory or type theory or whatever) such that the only thing one could do with two variables having the values from the set is compare whether they have identical values or not. Nothing else about these values is defined: no ordering, no difference, no ratio, no addition/multiplication, no builtin relationship to the naturals or whatever, etc.

What are some names for this kind of thing that I can use to find more reading about it and how it relates to the rest of math or logic?

Comment: A **set** is a collection of distinct elements in which order doesn't matter.  A **multi-set** is a collection of elements (with possible repitition) in which order doesn't matter.  Similar concepts include posets (a set of distinct elements with partial order), ordered sets (a set of distinct elements with order), and sequences (an ordered multiset).

Comment: I know, but it doesn't happen to help with my question because I'm asking about the nature of the elements as values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're called [abstract sets](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/set).

Personally, I would simply call this a "set," or perhaps a "mere set" or "unstructured set" to emphasize that there's no further structure around.

Comment: I chose this because simply looking up "set" does not help at all with the lack of structure among the values. Thanks.

Comment: Abstract set is also the term used by Lawvere in "Sets for Mathematics".

Comment: Yes, this seems to be closely related to ETCS and SEAR

Answer (score 0):

A **set** is a collection of distinct elements in which order doesn't matter.  A **multi-set** is a collection of elements (with possible repitition) in which order doesn't matter.

Neither of these (or the next terms below) require or need any operations to be defined for them.  For example, $\{ziggyswooglehorn, 5, \color{#C00}{\rm Red}\}$ is an example of a set with the elements $ziggyswooglehorn$, $5$, and $\color{#C00}{\rm Red}$ contained in it.  There is no mention however of what operations apply to or information you can extract about the elements in question except for their equality or inclusion in the set.  That is not to say that you *cannot* define such operations, it is just that they are not yet defined.

Similar concepts include posets (a set of distinct elements with partial order), ordered sets (a set of distinct elements with order), and sequences (an ordered multiset).

We could also consider the set $\mathbb{Z}=\{\dots,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,\dots\}$.  Without more information, we cannot say if there is in fact any operations that we can use with it.  If we wish to consider a set with operations and orders if the operations and/or order is not implicitly understood, we would write $(\mathbb{Z},+,\times,\leq)$, or something like $(A,\spadesuit,\heartsuit,\smile)$, where we can define also what it means to do $x\spadesuit y$.

Comment: Okay, so I understand at least this much, so I suppose it isn't about set theory, but things which could be built on top of set theory; so what is it called if you are considering the values in a set as only participating in an identity relation? (Mutating my terminology as needed, I don't know the proper words for everything). Edit: I understand that the values in a set are supposed to be unique, doesn't this imply something about some kind of identity/equality being defined on the values?

Comment: @onlyidentity Yes.  $\in$, $\notin$ and $=$ are all defined for elements in a set.  $x\in X$ if and only if $x$ is an element of $X$, $x\notin X$ if and only if $x$ is not an element of $X$, and $x=y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are in fact the same element of the set.  Keeping in mind that the $=$ I refer to here is such that an element is only equal to itself and nothing else in the set.

Comment: After looking up abstract sets, I gather that the missing insight is that with a bit of notation like "{5, Red}" there is actually no particular meaning to 5 or Red in any other system, they are completely arbitrary labels.

Answer (score 0):

The technical term for a set of values having no properties except that values are distinct is "set".

Comment: Material sets do not satisfy this claim, and via ZFC seem to be a very common way of thinking about sets.

Comment: Err...what?${}$

Comment: onlyidentity is right, see [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/set). This distinction really ought to be more widely appreciated.